# How do i create a newsgroup indexer and downloader?

Tags: .net, newsgroup

Been searching on google and might be that im searching for the wronge things.

How can i index a newsgroup server ?
If i already have a list of nzb files, how hard is it to write a little command line tool that downloads them?

Answer (score 0):

A vague question.

A list of NZB files will not help you.

Indexing a newsgroup server means you will have to write a little library to download all the posts of the usenet server. Just the headers(topics) take a big amount of Gigabytes just to store. I believe you have to have several Terabytes available to be able to store just all the headers.

A little less storage hungry would be to just index the last X days, but might get big anyway.

Once you have all the post headers, you will have to use some logic to group together all the posts that would be one release of any kind (movie/program/ISO). For each group you create, you combine these to an NZB xml file which you can use for your favorite usenet downloader.

But if your question is that you have several URLs for NZB files you wish to download, there is a nice tool called [webget](http://www.websitescreenshots.com/Utilities.aspx) that you can use to download any URL file.

Comment: My question was about both. Wanted to know how i can search for posts on a newsgroup. And if i had a nzb file, how to download the content. :)

Comment: There are open source indexers out there (so no need to write your own, just get one and run it privately). Check the forums over at sabnzbd. They are currently down because of the storm of NZBMatrix being down.